# how to check if a string is a composition of another string?

Tags: erlang

I would like to know how check if a string is a composition of another in the case bellow :

```
isIn("xy","xyxy") -> true
isIn("xy","xyxyx") -> true
isIn("xy","xyxyy") -> false
```

I have done this :

```
isIn(X,Y) -> 
case string:substr(Y,1,length(X)) == X of
    true -> true;
    false -> false
end
```

but I dont know how to continue checking the rest of the string .

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to "rotate" the substring while working through the string you're checking, comparing character by character:

```
is_in(_, []) -> true;
is_in([H|T1], [H|T2]) -> is_in(T1++[H], T2);
is_in(_,_) -> false.
```

The first clause of `is_in/2` states that if we've checked the entire second argument such that it's now the empty string, then the answer is true. The second clause verifies via pattern matching that the heads of the two strings are identical, and if so, calls recursively with the head of the first string rotated to its tail and the head of the second string dropped. The final clause of `is_in/2` returns false to handle the case of the heads of the strings not matching.

There are likely additional checks you need on the initial arguments, such as ensuring the length of the first string is less than or equal to that of the second string, ensuring that neither string is empty, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is better performant solution

```
is_in(S1, S2) ->
    is_in(S1, false, S1, S2).

is_in(S1, A, [H|T1], [H|T2]) ->
    is_in(S1, A, T1, T2);
is_in([_|_] = S1, _, [], S2) ->
    is_in(S1, true, S1, S2);
is_in(_, A, _, []) -> A;
is_in(_, _, _, _) -> false.
```